# Why 2[a] can pass compiling if only declare int a[3] in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

Why 2[a] can be compiled if only declare int a[3] in C.

```
 1  #include <stdio.h>
 2
 3  int main(int argc, char **argv)
 4  {
 5      int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
 6      printf("a[2] is: %d\n", a[2]);
 7      printf("2[a] is: %d\n", 2[a]);
 8
 9      return 0;
10  }
```

And the output both 3, how to explain it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `a[2]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(a+2)`, which is the same as `*(2+a)` or `2[a]`.

Comment: Some would call it syntactic vinegar. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Because all `a[2]` means in C is `*(a + 2)`, and so `*(2 + a)` works just as well, which could also be written `2[a]`.

Answer (score 2):

An expression is composed of one or more operands. The simplest form of an expression consists of a single literal constant or object. The result, in general, is the operand's rvalue.

As per the C standard:

**6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an
>   expression in square brackets [] is a
>   subscripted designation of an element
>   of an array object. The definition of
>   the subscript operator [] is that
>   E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).
>   Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary + operator, if E1
>   is an array object (equivalently, a
>   pointer to the initial element of an
>   array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of
>   E1 (counting from zero).

So, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)` and `b[a]`. where `a` and `b` can be any expression.